# Why would Obi-Wan Kenobi say this?

Tags: star-wars

### Why do I sense that we've picked up another pathetic life form?

When [Qui-Gon Jinn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-gon_jinn) says he is going back, [Obi-Wan Kenobi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-wan_Kenobi) says:

> Why do I sense that we've picked up another pathetic life form?

In the context of the conversation, both Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan know that he is going back for Anakin, so I don't understand why Obi-Wan would say something like this.

Obi-Wan was the one who measured Anakin's blood for [Midi-chlorians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian) and said they were off the chart, quoting him:

> The reading is off the chart, over 20,000, even Master Yoda dosen't
>   have a Midi-chlorian count that high...

Being that Anakin has a Midi-chlorian count higher than Yoda which obviously is something very special, how could Obi-Wan say:

> Why do I sense that we've picked up another pathetic life form?

I would think the topic of conversation would be, when are you going to bring that little boy back to [Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant) with us? Not "Why do I sense that we've picked up another pathetic life form?"

The meaning I take from that is that he does not think Anakin is worth bringing with them.

Comment: Keep in mind that Obi-wan was against training Anakin at this point. The kid was too old, and they had more important things to do. Plus, Anakin can't use the Force yet, so he is still pretty pathetic.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, really, when did he say that?

Comment: If I had the time to find the quote, I'd write up an answer. As it is, maybe I'm wrong. I'll see if I can follow up later.

Comment: Having some natural talent does not preclude one from being pathetic.  In fact, that can actually underscore the point.

Comment: The vibe I got from Obi-Wan when watching this in theaters (and every time since) is that he was utterly unimpressed with what he had seen from Anakin thus far. So, like Jar Jar, Anakin was just another pathetic life form in Obi-Wan's eyes.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh His use of the force was limited at the time, but surely he must have been using it when racing pods.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is actually a very reasonable thing for Obi-Wan to say. He's clearly calling back to an earlier statement, regarding Jar-Jar:

> **Obi-Wan:** Master, why do you keep dragging these pathetic life forms along
>   with us?
>
> <sup>*The Phantom Menace* (1999)</sup>

He's making a small (and admittedly unfunny) joke at his master's expense.

- That being said, it's not at all clear that Obi-Wan actually knows *who* Qui-Gon is bringing back; notable is Qui-Gon's next line (emphasis mine):

  > **Obi-Wan:** Why do I sense we've picked up another pathetic life form?
  >
  > **Qui-Gon: It's the boy who's responsible for getting those parts.**
  >
  > <sup>*The Phantom Menace* (1999)</sup>

  But perhaps he did know, or else made an educated guess, in which case I fall back on:
- "Pathetic" need not mean "useless"; in fact, one [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pathetic)<sup>1</sup> is:

  > Arousing pity, especially through vulnerability or sadness.

  By any measure, regardless of how powerful he is with the Force, Anakin qualifies as that. Although the word "pathetic" can be used as an insult, in this context it seems doubtful that Obi-Wan is using it that way; it's not very Jedi-like, and Obi-Wan has no reason to insult Anakin<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Arguably the primary definition, even if it's not the one commonly intended in the modern, cynical 2010's

<sup>2</sup> Yet.

Comment: The meaning of pathetic, 'miserably inadequate'. So Anakin , with the highest Midi-chlorian count , higher than Yoda is 'miserably inadequate'?

Comment: @KyloRen You did read my answer, yes? That's one definition of the word, but is not the only one; words can mean more than one thing

Comment: I did, but 99.9999999% of the time 'Pathetic' means the later. Does it not?

Comment: @KyloRen On the Internet, "pathetic" is an insult approximately 101% of the time. But Obi-Wan isn't on the Internet and has no reason to insult Anakin. From context, it's vastly more likely that he means that Anakin is pitiable, similar to how I call my dog "pathetic" when she gives me puppy-dog eyes

Comment: Hmm, I don't disagree with that, UV from me.

Comment: In Legends continuity, Qui-Gon had a bad habit of allowing creatures to tag along with he and Obi-Wan, even the ones that caused them trouble. It was all part of his "Living Force" philosophy, whereas most Jedi preferred the "Unifying Force" philosophy. Basically, Qui-Gon believed that the NOW was more important than any long-term plans.

Comment: @Omegacron Funny you mention that, because I just re-read [*Life, Death, and the Living Force*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Life,_Death,_and_the_Living_Force) the other day. The Force moves in mysterious ways

Comment: Well, in the german translation of the film he says primitive life form. Which fits in much better from my point of view.

Comment: I like to think it's an in-joke between Qui-Gonn and Obi-Wan that came about because on one occasion the lifeform Qui-Gonn brought with them turned out to actually be pathetic and useless. "Obi-Wan, I'm going out for groceries, be back soon." "Do try not to bring home any more pathetic life forms, master." "IT WAS ONE TIME, OBI-WAN!"

Comment: @DisturbedNeo The one occasion you're referring to is Jar Jar. And Obi-wan has rights to bag on Qui-Gonn forever over picking up that pathetic life form.